# Routing between EC2 instances not coming through

Tags: amazon-ec2, routing, amazon-vpc

I want to set up a VPN from one EC2 instance in a default VPC the other instances in the same VPC can use so I am doing some initial tests.  I have 2 test instances running and they can ping each other.  When I route a test public IP from one to the other the packets do go out from eth0 of the sender instance (as seen by `tcpdump` with the expected target MAC address (so I guess I have host routing set right) but **never arrive** at the target instance.  I have tested this 2 ways, one via 172.31.0.1 , and also directly using the IP of the other instance as the gateway.  `iptables` on both hosts (*Ubuntu* and *Amazon Linux* both tested) is empty.  The test public IP was added as a route on the VPC master routing table using the test receive instance as the gateway.

My goal is that instances I launch in that VPC that send to any non-VPC IP end up going to the instance I run the VPN on (still undecided between IPsec or OpenVPN).  **How can I get the packets to go through on EC2 over a default VPC**?  I suspect there is more to this than I find in the AWS docs or via Google (maybe some other EC2 object ... do I have all the concepts right?).

Comment: You cannot route EC2 public IP addresses inside of a VPC. Is that what you are trying to do? You can only NAT from a pubic IP using your own NAT instance, or by associating an EIP, in which case AWS will handle the 1:1 NAT for you.

Comment: no, it was a *non-AWS public address* in 44.0.0.0/8  i picked that for testing. as a ham-radio operator i knew i did not expect get that over the real internet so i could do route table testing with it without breaking access to IPs the VPC might need to reach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routing of traffic to a VPN concentrator is done in the same way routing is done to a NAT instance.

- [Disable the IP source/dest check](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck) on the target instance to allow the traffic through, and then
- use the VPC routing tables (not static routes in individual instances) to forward the traffic to the VPN concentrator by its instance-ID/elastic network interface-ID.

The instances using such a route as their default route will, of necessity, only have private IP addresses assigned.

Comment: tested and now it works.  it was the *source/dest check* i did not do.  i am not doing NAT so the AWS documentation can be misleading.

Comment: To clarify this a bit having hacked around for a while today, you definitely do need to turn off the source/dest check. If you have multi-homed hosts, you have to disable on the instance and the additional ENIs. You *can* use host routes on instances so long as the traffic doesn't need to go via the implicit router to get to the target instance (in the question given, VPC routes are probably more appropriate though).